# Integration of a logarithmic function.

Tags: integration

What are the step by step integration techniques to integrate $\ln(a(x^2) +b)$?

Comment: I made an edit. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Is the integration with respect to a, x, or b? I am pretty sure it's x, but I want to make sure before writing an answer. Also, is it definite or indefinite.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention,it is integration with respect to x.

Comment: So you mean $$\int \ln(ax^2+b)dx?$$

Comment: Apply integration by parts!

Comment: Ok thanks.But when I have put it first at wolframalpha(web link given below) I can't understand this like what is O(x4),Like etc a bunch of things.So how can I explain this as simple as possible?web link -http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(ax%5E2+%2Bb)

Answer (score 1):

Use Integration by parts. Let $u=\ln(ax^2+b)$ and $dv=dx$. Then $$du=\frac{2ax}{ax^2+b}$$ and $v=x$. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\int \ln(ax^2+b)dx&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-\int \frac{x(2ax)}{ax^2+b}dx\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-\int \frac{2ax^2}{ax^2+b}dx\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-\int \bigg[2-\frac{2b}{ax^2+b}\bigg]dx\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-2x+2b\int\frac{dx}{ax^2+b}\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-2x+2b\cdot\frac{1}{b}\int\frac{dx}{\frac{ax^2}{b}+1}dx\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-2x+2\int\frac{dx}{\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x\bigg)^2+1}\\
&=x\ln(ax^2+b)-2x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}\arctan\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}x\bigg)+C\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: On integrating by parts, 
$$I = x\ln(ax^2 + b)- \int\dfrac{2ax^2}{ax^2+b}dx$$
$$=x\ln(ax^2 + b)- 2\int\left(\dfrac{ax^2+b}{ax^2+b}-\dfrac{b}{ax^2+b}\right)dx$$
$$=x\ln(ax^2 + b)- 2\left(x-\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{ab}}\arctan{\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}}x}\right)$$